# Stopping processes using Event() not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I recently migrated from using threads to multiprocessing and have had to make several adjustments.  One is how to handle shutting things down when CTRL-C is received.  Depending on how I try to do things, either everything just sits there and doesn't stop or things crash.  I know when it crashes, this relates to KeyboardInterrupt being received in the child processes.

I was previously defining a function in my primary process that ran when SIGINT was received and it raises an Exception that I catch when then the user hits CTRL-C.  Inside the child processes, I am using multiprocessing.Event() to control breaking out of loops.  When that exception triggers, I set the Event.

I have tried setting SIGINT to be ignored inside the process but that results in things hanging as previously mentioned.

Here is some example code...  what am I missing?

```
import multiprocessing
import signal

def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, service_shutdown)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, service_shutdown)

    try:
        process = MyProc(
            id=0,
            name='MyProc',
            args=['some_data']
        )
        process.start()
        process.join()

    except ServiceExit:
        process.shutdown_flag.set()

class MyProc(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, id, name, args):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.shutdown_flag = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.data = args[0]

    def run(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIG_IGN)

        while not self.shutdown_flag.is_set():
            print(self.data)
            self.shutdown_flag.wait(2)

class ServiceExit(Exception):
    """
    Custom exception which is used to trigger the clean exit
    of all running processes and the main program.
    """
    pass

def service_shutdown(signum, frame):
    """
    Triggered when the user hits CTRL-C.
    
    Raises ServiceExit to allow for graceful shutdown of processes.
    """

    raise ServiceExit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue on Windows only.  If I run the script above in Linux, it exits fine.  On Windows, it hangs.  If I do a different implementation where I disable SIGINT with SIG_IGN in main, then create the processes, then turn the signals back on, everything works great in Linux but I get the KeyboardInterrupt in Windows.  Any way to make this work without doing a try/except for KeyboardInterrupt in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the trick is *not* to ignore CTRL-C in your subprocess. Here instead of using `signal`, I am just handling `KeyBoardInterrupt` exception. This works in both Windows and Linux:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def main():
    try:
        process = MyProc(
            id=0,
            name='MyProc',
            args=['some_data']
        )
        process.start()
        process.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        process.join() # process can be joined multiple times

class MyProc(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, id, name, args):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.data = args[0]

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                print(self.data)
                time.sleep(2)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is what I ended up having to do.